# Rails 3 - getting and comparison of IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, controller, ip

I found through [google](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what%20is%20my%20ip) my IP address and now I try to make a redirect based on the IP address.

To the **HomeController#index** I set followings:

```
unless request.remote_ip.to_s == '1.2.3.4'
    redirect_to 'http://www.some_page.com'
    return
end
```

But this doesn't works, because I am always redirected on the *some_page.com*... What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying this on a local machine? Then your "remote IP" from the server's point of view would always be [127.0.0.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/127.0.0.1), not your external IP.

Anyways, see what `request.remote_ip` is actually returning. Maybe it'll shed some light.

Comment: no, I am trying it on the web. `request.remote_ip` return 1.2.3.4 (of course that's not real) and this IP address I compare in my `index` action - I updated my first post. But still I dont understand, why is the page always redirected...